# What's the melody of Joker's song in The Killing Joke?

Tags: dc, music, the-joker, the-killing-joke

When Joker is speaking to Gordon over the intercom in *Batman: The Killing Joke*, the enunciation and rhyming scheme (and the fact that he asks for music) make it pretty obvious that the Joker is singing. Is there an official source on how the song was supposed to be sung? Melody, timing, pitch, etc?

[image]
[image]

Lyrics:

> When the world is full of care
>   And every headline screams despair,
>   All is rape, starvation, war and life is vile
>
> Then there’s a certain thing I do
>   Which I shall pass along to you,
>   That’s always guaranteed to make me smile:
>
> I go loo-oo-oony as a light-bulb battered bug!
>   Simply loo-oo-oony, sometimes foam and chew the rug!
>
> Mister, life is swell
>   In a padded cell,
>   It’ll chase those blues away:
>   You can trade your gloom
>   For a rubber room
>   And injections twice a day!
>
> Just go loo-oo-oony like an acid casualty,
>   Or a moo-oo-oonie, or a preacher on T.V.
>
> When the human race
>   Wears an anxious face,
>   When the bomb hangs overhead,
>   When your kid turns blue,
>   It won’t worry you,
>   You can smile and nod instead.
>
> When you’re loo-oo-oony, then you just don’t give a fig,
>   Man’s so pu-uu-uny, and the universe so big!
>
> If you hurt inside,
>   Get certified,
>   And if life should treat you bad...
>
> Don't get ee-ee-even.
>   Get mad.
>   -  *Batman:  The Killing Joke*, Alan Moore and Brian Bolland

Comment: Do you have a video link or something?

Comment: @RedCaio - Pictures added.

Comment: Unfortunately, we just don't know.  Alan Moore wrote the lyrics, but he's not very open about his previous projects, and he isn't especially  fond of this story in particular.  I doubt he has ever mentioned the melody, if he even wrote one.

Comment: Hmm.  He is an [amateur musician](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alan_Moore#Marvel_UK.2C_2000AD.2C_and_Warrior:_1980.E2.80.931984) and he's recorded with a former member of *Bauhaus*, so maybe he did have a tuning in mind.

Comment: I've found two different interpretations of it on YouTube, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=f9kl-Rexu7M and https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KOb4fOGQHCE, but I don't think either is official.

Comment: @Web Cheber Woah, great edit, thanks. At least three of these votes should probably be yours. If you want to make your comment an answer I can wait a few hours and accept it. At the absolute worst, I'll probably get my answer when the animated movie comes out.

Comment: I couldn't help reading it to the tune of "Always look on the bright side of life", but maybe that's just me... "loo-oo-oony" matching with "al-ways look on" in the chorus.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here you have it sung by Mark Hamill in animated version of "Killing Joke":

Answer (score 2):

<sup>I like both the Monty Python suggestions. The lyrics fit the melody of *Always Look On the Bright Side* rather well: on reflection I would think that this is rather more likely than the suggestion I am about to make, but I’ll share it anyway for consideration:</sup>

I used to believe at the time of publication that the melody could be loosely based upon *Button Up your Overcoat,* known for its chorus lyric:

> Take Good Care of Yourself (You Belong To Me).

At the time Alan Moore was writing *The Killing Joke,* it was being reused as a jingle for Mentadent-P toothpaste in the UK; so it was constantly in the public consciousness. Moore’s lyrics could act as a parody of the original, while the original lyrics themselves rather perfectly describe the Joker’s relationship with Batman.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is no one knows for sure, but it is pretty clear that is a rewrite of "The Galaxy Song" by Monty Python.

It follows the same schema of paragraphs topics, references it with "the universe" and just reading it you get the same general rythm.

I don't think it was supposed to be a 1 to 1 thing, but just something very similar.